# How to sort on column for rows containing a certain word

Tags: vim

I want to sort on a certain column only  for rows containing a certain word. I don't want to see rows not containing that word. For example I have this text file:

```
 sdf ggfds   7
 sdf sgs     5
 sdf dfgs    3
 foo dffg    2
 bar dffg    2
 sdf sddfg   4
```

I want to sort 3rd column for rows containing only "sdf" word (doesnt have to be in a first column)

and I want to see this output:

```
 sdf dfgs    3
 sdf sddfg   4
 sdf sgs     5
 sdf ggfds   7
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pipe your input to an external command:

```
:%!grep sdf | sort -n -k3
```

Details:

1. select the whole content using '%'
2. pipe it to an external command using '!'
3. grep onyl the lines containing 'sdf'
4. sort these lines numerically (-n) on the third field (-k3)

Comment: Of course, this is only any good if you're on a computer with grep and sort installed - many Vim users on Windows will find this won't work and may not want to install gnuwin32 or cygwin.

Comment: So far, this is the best and the most intuitive answer!

Answer (score 8):

2 vim commands:

```
:v/sdf/d
:sort n /[^[:digit:]]*/
```

- first deletes all lines that do not contain 'sdf'
- second sorts numbers ignoring non-numbers

Comment: +1: A good native-Vim way to do it without having to spawn an external shell.

Comment: an intersting way,Maxim, but  I also want to sort on a specific column

Comment: yep, it comes that os's sort make it easier to sort by a specific column but you can use :sort n /\v(\S+\s+){2}/ to do the same within vim as Al pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

Maxim Kim has already given an excellent answer and I was going to add this in a comment, but it just got too complicated so I'll stick it in an answer:

You could simplify the pattern by using:

```
:v/sdf/d
sort n /\D*/
```

as `\D` is equivalent to `[^[:digit:]]` and is a lot less typing.  For more information, see

```
:help \D
```

To match on the third field specifically, rather than just the first digit, use

```
:sort n /\(\S\+\s+\)\{2}/`
```

or

```
:sort n /\v(\S+\s+){2}/
```

See:

```
:help :sort
:help \S
:help \s
:help pattern.txt
:help \v
```

As an aside, some find it easier to remember `:g!/sdf/d`, which does the same as `:v/sdf/d` - `:g!` is the opposite of `:g` and is identical to `:v`.

```
:help :v
:help :g
```

Answer (score 3):

Sort by 2nd column by selecting it in visual mode (e.g. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>), then run:

```
!sort
```

or to sort by 3rd column

```
sort -k 3
```

or

```
:sort /.*\%3v/
```

Alternatively select the lines you wish to sort using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> command. Then enter

```
!sort -k 3n
```

or use the below code to tell Vim to skip the first two words in every line and sort on whatever follows:

```
:%sort /^\S\+\s\+\S\+\s\+/
```

or i.e. sort by 8th line:

```
:sort /.*\%55v/
```

The 'virtual' specification is the absolute number of column , which treats spaces + tabs as single character (shortly, it doesn't count tabs as eight spaces),

so to sort by last column:

```
:%sort /\<\S\+\>$/ r
```