# Sort in vim while ignoring articles ('A' and 'The')

Tags: vim

I have a vim file that looks like the following:

```
ABBA
Duran Duran
The Beatles
The Rolling Stones
Styx
```

Using vim's sort command results in this output:

```
ABBA
Duran Duran
Styx
The Beatles
The Rolling Stones
```

What I want to do is to ignore articles like 'A' and 'The' when sorting. So expected output would be like this

```
ABBA
The Beatles
Duran Duran
The Rolling Stones
Styx
```

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372993/how-to-sort-on-column-for-rows-containing-a-certain-word

Answer (score 14, accepted):

look at `:help :sort`

> When /{pattern}/ is specified and there is no [r] flag
>   the text matched with {pattern} is skipped, so that
>   you sort on what comes after the match.
>   Instead of the slash any non-letter can be used.

```
:sort /^\(A \|The \)*/
```

This make sort of:

```
(ABBA)
The (Beatles)
(Duran Duran)
The (Rolling Stones)
(Styx)
```